# write()-ing data including '\0' in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to write a char array to a socket in C++. However, the data I wish to write is raw image data and thus includes '\0', which signals the termination of the string. Is there anyway to send all of the data, including the '\0'?

UPDATE: The issue was in the use of `strlen()`, not `write()`

Comment: Look at it as 1 `BYTE` of binary data, not an ASCII character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The send() function doesn't care about null bytes. It sends the length you tell it to send.

Answer (score 1):

Both [`send()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) and [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) take a `void*` buffer and the number of bytes to write. Therefore the issue of NUL terminators does not arise at the API level.

As far as the application code is concerned, just don't use C strings to represent binary data and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to write the null character into the TCP string.

I, personally, heard of no TCP API that would treat it as a termination of anything. Typically, you specify buffer and length, and all else matters not.